# How do I get just one column with this code?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which name is product barcode and i want to return one column by using executescalar .I dont want to return datatable.Nevertheless my query returs rows .I just need barcode. Please help !!

I can figure out the problem by using recursive select loop but ı want to solve this problem by using partition by .

```
select BARCODE
      ,PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE
      , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by PRODUCT_NO order by PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE desc )
  from PRODUCT_BARCODE 
 where PRODUCT_NO='111333666';
```

I expect output like this:

```
25000111133335555
```

it will return barcode like this. Query execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the `barcode` from the row with the highest `product_barcode_type_code` for the specified product then you can do it without a subquery or explicit ranking function using [`last`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC):

```
select max(barcode) keep (dense_rank last order by product_barcode_type_code) as barcode
from product_barcode
where product_no = 111333666;
```

You can include a `partition by` clause but there's no point as you're filtering on a single `product_no` anyway.

Very quick demo:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with product_barcode (product_no, product_barcode_type_code, barcode) as (
  select 111333666, 1, 1234 from dual
  union all select 111333666, 2, 2345 from dual
  union all select 111333666, 3, 25000111133335555  from dual
)
select max(barcode) keep (dense_rank last order by product_barcode_type_code) as barcode
from product_barcode
where product_no = 111333666;

          BARCODE
-----------------
25000111133335555
```

(I've assumed your `product_no`, at least, is a number type rather than a string, and thus omitted the single quotes you had around the literal value you're searching for; but if it is actually a string then include those of course..)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select BARCODE + PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE + partBarCode
FROM 
(
select BARCODE
      ,PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE
  , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by PRODUCT_NO order by 
PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE desc ) as partBarCode
from PRODUCT_BARCODE 
where PRODUCT_NO='111333666'
) as res
```

This assumes that all fields are of the same type Nvarchar() else they will be summarized as per integer.

Comment: The question is for Oracle - which doesn't allow `+` as a concatenation operator for strings, so it will always (try to) add the values together as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select to_char (BARCODE ) || to_char( PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE)  from (
select BARCODE
      ,PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE
      , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by PRODUCT_NO order by PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE desc ) rn
  from PRODUCT_BARCODE 
 where PRODUCT_NO='111333666'
)
Where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select concat(BARCODE,PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE) as barcode from 
(
select BARCODE
      ,PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE
      , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by PRODUCT_NO order by PRODUCT_BARCODE_TYPE_CODE desc ) as rn
  from PRODUCT_BARCODE 
 where PRODUCT_NO='111333666'
)A where rn=1
```